# What is the reason for the existence of undefined variable in the global scope in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I've found many discussions about *undefined* as value e.g. how to check if is equal etc. But what is the "engineering" reason for the existence of the *undefined* as a global variable? There is no *null* variable in opposite...

```
console.log(undefined in this);  // logs true
console.log(null in this);  // logs false
```

Comment: The reason why global `undefined` is used as a reference to *real* `undefined` value is behind my understanding. Probably this remained unchanged from the previous implementations. There is a good article about that [here](http://designpepper.com/blog/drips/redefining-undefined) but still gives no reason for the issue.

Comment: Contact Brendan Eich and then report back here :)

Answer (score 5):

In JavaScript, `null` is a reserved word; `undefined` isn't, but is *implemented* by the environment as a global variable with a value of `undefined`.

You'll notice you can *change* the value of `undefined`, but not of `null`, **except** in strict mode (which will throw an error) or ES5 (which will ignore the assignment.)

Now, why `undefined` is not reserved, I do not know.

Comment: You can't change the value of `undefined` under ES5 and in strict mode.

Comment: @Mathletics: You were still half right though... hope you don't mind my edit.

Comment: @Matt I'd better say *except in ES5 and in strict mode*, since each can be used separately. The first just ignores the assignment, whilst the second throws an exception.

Comment: @Matt I did have somewhere, yeah ;)

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that ECMAScript defines [a property of the global object called *undefined*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1.3) whose initial value is *undefined*. This object is created [before entering any execution context](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1), so it always exists before any code is run.

It is likely a convenience for testing for the undefined value, otherwise it would be common do to things like:

```
var undefined;

// test against undefined.

function foo() {

    // And maybe here too
    var undefined;

   // test against undefined.
}
```

Since the global *undefined* property is not write protected, it is common to do things like:

```
(function(global, undefined) {

  // In here you can be sure undefined has the value undefined

}(this));
```

#### Edit

In summary, the goal seems to have been to create two separate ways of returning a value of "there is no value", where *undefined* means "my value is not defined at all", whereas *null* means "I do not have a value".

e.g.

```
function getElement(id) {
  if (document && document.getElementById) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
  }
  // return undefined implied
}
```

If the above function returns `null`, you know it ran successfully but didn't find an element with the provided id, whereas if it returns `undefined`, you know it didn't even try.

In regard to:

> There is no null variable in opposite

I guess you are saying "why is `undefined` a global variable whereas `null` is global object.

The answer is the same: because that's how the spec was written. One explanation (not a reason) is that JavaScript was prematurely optimised and there are a few fundamental issues that should have been sorted earlier, but it's too late to change them now (and has been for many years).

Perhaps it would have been much better (IMHO) if `undefined` was implemented just like `null` (i.e. as a read–only property of the global object) and that:

```
typeof undefined === 'undefined'
```

and

```
typeof null === 'null'
```

since that is what they actually are. But changing that now might create more issues than it solves.

And then there is `NaN`…

Comment: But why is it a property and not a reserved word? Your answer doesn't get any further than mine ;-)

Comment: I think I explained exactly why (briefly, because that's how it's defined in ECMA-262), however I've updated my answer.

Comment: But why does the spec define it thusly? You see what I'm getting at here?

Comment: I feel like I've read an essay on the topic "Speculations about 'undefined' type in JavaScript" :). @FelixKling is right -- no one can answer this question better than the actual authors of the language.